# SharePoint - Select different Account with same email address

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have two MS-Accounts: one business and one private. BOTH have the same email address, but only one has got SharePoint access rights. I was using different passwords for these account and this code worked:

```
Dim SPOCredentials As SharePointOnlineCredentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(userLogin, pwd)
```

Now I changed the passwords to the same one (yes I know one shouldn't do that) and I cannot login to SharePoint.

How can I tell the SharePointCredentials which account has to be used?

This is my current code:

```
Dim SPOCredentials As SharePointOnlineCredentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(userLogin, pwd)
Dim SPCredentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential(userLogin, pwd)
Using ctx As ClientContext = New ClientContext(SiteUrl)
  Try
    ctx.Credentials = SPOCredentials
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    [...]
```

The error in ctx.ExecuteQuery() is

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 'The sign-in name or
> password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.'

Edit: This does not work either:

```
Dim SPOCredentials As SharePointOnlineCredentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(userLogin, pwd)
Using ctx As ClientContext = New ClientContext(SiteUrl)
  ctx.Credentials = SPOCredentials
  Dim library As List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(docLibTitle)
  ctx.Load(library, Function(x) x.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)
  ctx.ExecuteQuery()
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

•   You can correct your code by setting up the context first, i.e., the site for which you are passing the specific credentials and then getting to call the specific email address by list name and ID since though both the personal and work accounts share the same email addresses but have different URLs to sign in. Consider the example as stated below for your requirements. You can use the below script as a reference example to login using the personal or work account email address: -

```
   ‘ #Set parameter values
     $SiteURL="your site collection url"
     $UserID="your user ID"
     $ListName="your list name"
     $FieldName="your list column name" #Internal Name
     $ListItemID="your list item ID"
     #Get Credentials to connect
     $Cred= Get-Credential
     $Credentials = New-Object 
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, 
     $Cred.Password)
     #Setup the context
     $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
     $Ct. Credentials = $Credentials
     #Get the List & Item to update
     $List = $Ctx.Web.lists.GetByTitle($ListName) 
     $ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ListItemID)
     $Ctx.Load($ListItem)
     $Ctx.ExecuteQuery() ‘
```

•   If you execute your csom sharepoint online query by referring as above, you will be able to login using the specific email address to the work or personal sharepoint online account through the ListItem ID or Internal Name used while creating the account.

Please refer the below link for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/429142/user-email-id-casing-different-in-sharepoint-onlin.html

Comment: Either I do not get the point or it doesn't work. I edited my question and added a new code snippet in order to use the code in your givven order. The error is still the same